# How do I request a fullscreen window on iOS using SDL2

Tags: ios, iphone, fullscreen, sdl-2

How do I make my SDL2 GLES application execute in fullscreen on iOS?

From *Xcode/Targets/General/Deployment* Info I've checked both "Hide Status Bar" and "Requires fullscreen".
I initialize my SDL_Window with `SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN | SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI | SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS | SDL_WINDOW_MAXIMIZED`

Still, the application does not run in fullscreen, there are two black bars at both sides of the screen (the app runs only in landscape mode).

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is having this problem, I had to add a "Default-568h@2x.png" load-image to the project, and then it worked.